# Isotope shudder and layoutComplete loop

Tags: css, jquery-isotope

I have a responsive isotope layout, using the packery algorithm and percentage widths. However at certain screen sizes, the columns start to "shudder" very slightly, as if moving backwards and forwards between two positions. It's not triggering a window.resize event, but I do notice that the isotope "layoutComplete" event is constantly being called (whether or not the shuddering is visible), suggesting that the layout is never "settling" into a particular configuration.

A bit more info:
I have a three column layout, and the problem *seems* to stem from the column sizes being 33% - if I lower this value to 32% the shuddering stops. This suggests - I think - that the entire width of the row is greater than 100% and isotope is trying to fit into 100%.

Has anyone else ever experienced this? It doesn't seem to be the content, as it still happens when I simply use coloured blocks.

Unfortunately I cannot share the link as it's for a corporate client with an NDA.

Comment: There is no need to share a link. Just create a jsfiddle/codepen/jsbin with a demonstration of the problem with dummy content instead of your clients data. That's even much better to get help because people can see the result AND the code in the same time.

Comment: try using `width: calc(100% / 3); width: 33.333%` on the grid-element in your CSS. Also make sure you're using `percentPosition: true` option on isotope

Comment: I'm not sure where one puts "embarrassing realizations" in the thread... the cause was inadvertently using setInterval rather than setTimeout on an isotope refresh. Late night :x